# Express post array gets undefined?

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, http, post

My problem is that when i post an array of IDs to my express server from either supertest/axios or Insomnia the req.body.ids array is undefined.

This is my code:

```
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
    
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(jsonParser);

router.post('/saveIds', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // Here I can see the array of IDs and other parameters
  console.log(req.body.playerIds) // This returns undefined
})
```

How come `req.body.playerIds` is undefined but is visible if i only console.log `req.body`?

Comment: An array doesn't *have* an ids property, even if the objects in it do.

Comment: Show us the code that makes the request

Comment: This is the request in insomnia:
```{ "user": "bar", "playerIds": ["VcqFjBcoZSd", "8SWDJQlvKg", "u2H_Soyz_3"], "name": "foo" }```

Comment: you need to use playerIds, console.log(req.body.playerIds)

Comment: As I wrote in my question, req.body.playerIds gives undefined, but req.body shows it existing

Comment: What's inside `req.body`? is it the same with the request from insomnia?